# Networking programming - client - server not in the same LAN

Tags: python, network-programming, client-server, port

My friend and I trying to communicate each other using simple python client - server.
When we were in the same LAN , the communication was great.
Now , each of us is in his house and we can't connect beacuse of error 10060.
We read about the firewall problem , we tried to turn it off - and still not working.

What should we do?
Thank is advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be due to port forwarding, to fix this you would need to enable port forwarding on your router. Each router is different, but this is usually done by opening the router's webpage and setting port forwarding to the IP of your computer